# css animation + :nth-child() Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

In "theory" every odd entry of class `d` should go left, and every even - right. But all move left...
Any suggestions why could that be?

```
       .d {
            -webkit-transition:all 2s;
        }

        .d:nth-child(even):hover {
            left: -10%;
        }

        .d:nth-child(odd):hover {
            left: 10%;
        }
```

Comment: A working demo would be more clear to understand

Comment: Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/xAn2F/ can you add all your styles for `d` and your html too

Comment: hm, probs conflicts with something in bootstrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe your other code messing it up, here is a demo I made to show it does work.

### HTML:

```
<div id="con">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#con {
    position: relative;
}
#con div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
}
#con div:nth-child(even):hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10%;
    background: red;
}
#con div:nth-child(odd):hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    background: red;
}
```

Depends how you want to do it, in this demo I have used `position: absolute;` when you hover to move them to the sides. Hope this helps you.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/3z6tj/)

Comment: yeah, i see it works fine here... just got an conflict with bootstrap i guess

Comment: Would seem to be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` for correct animation. e.g.:

```
.d {
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    background:#1E5799;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: `position: relative;` doesn't change anything

Comment: I test (in Chrome)it, and it working fine. Might be other layout properties restricting it.

Comment: i mean it doesn't solve the issue. and works without declared `position` as well

Comment: OK, then I apologies! It was not working without using `position` on my system :) That was why I posted it.